# Using SSMTP and ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a project for school and I'm trying to use sSMTP to send emails from java to a user using a text file. Executing from the command line `ssmtp email@gmail.com < msg.txt` works just fine and sends me the email with the information contained in msg.txt. However, when I try to do it in java using ProcessBuilder it doesn't send an email.

```
`ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder;
 builder.command("ssmtp", "email@gmail.com", "<", "msg.txt");
 Process p = builder.start();`
```

I believe that it doesn't like where I try to pipe in msg.txt. If anyone knows a better way to do this that would be great. I haven't been able to find anything yet and am not sure how to do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to rely on the shell's redirect functionality (which as you see doesn't work), you can just read `msg.txt` and write it to the process' `OutputStream`. It'll be the same thing, but in code (and it'll be a better solution too).

Something along the lines of

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("ssmtp").start();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
String line = null;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("msg.txt")));
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    out.println(line);
out.close();
in.close();
```

However **if** you want to use shell redirection which I wouldn't recommend for anything serious, you need to execute the program which actually does the redirection, i.e. `bash`. The following should do the trick:

```
new ProcessBuilder("bash", "ssmtp", "email@gmail.com", "<", "msg.txt").start();
```

---

As dave_thompson_085 commented, it's even easier to do programmatic redirection. Things sure are easy these days!

```
new ProcessBuilder("ssmtp", "email@gmail.com").redirectInput(new File("msg.txt")).start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think to just read the file in. The only thing I needed to change was in the first line I needed to add the destination of the email as a command.

Comment: Since j7 ProcessBuilder can do redirection, but using method calls not the shell anglebracket syntaxes; see the javadoc. (The older more basic Runtime.exec can't.)