# Process Builder Arguments

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, processbuilder, arp

```
final String commands[] =  {"arp", "-n", "|" ,"grep", "98:5d:ad:3d:36:ef", "|", "awk '", "{print $1}", "'"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

I would like to retrieve the IP, given the MAC ADDRESS. 
When I insert this command to the terminal (ubuntu 16.04) it works. 
But it doesn't work when I use it in JAVA.

What am i doing wrong?

It only works when I run it like this:

```
final String commands[] =  {"arp", "-n"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Comment: I only get this:  exit: 255

Comment: @Daniele's answer is correct - the reason is that your Java code doesn't provide shell features, such as piping the output of one command to the next.

Comment: Near dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223605/using-ssmtp-and-processbuilder (`ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.exec` are alike in this respect, although they have other differences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke "sh" and pass to that program your piped command.
Try:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/sh", "-c",
               "arp -n | grep 98:5d:ad:3d:36:ef | awk '{print $1}'" );
```

Comment: Or just run `"arp","-n"` and use `String.contains` or `String.indexOf` to replace the `grep` and `String.split` or `Scanner` or `StringTokenizer` to replace the `awk $1`